# How do you adjust the mouse wheel in Windows NT 4?

Tags: mouse-wheel, windows-nt-4

I need to adjust the number of lines that the window scrolls when using the mouse wheel manually in Windows NT 4.  Any idea how to configure that?

Any registry hack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hunted around and found this old application that did the trick.

### [KatMouse](http://ehiti.de/katmouse/)

Answer (score 1):

That will probably depend on your mouse drivers. I don't remember NT4 having built in wheel support.